# Shutdown command prompt strange behavior

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, regedit

Recently I've found something strange behavior of shutdown command prompt. When I type shutdown -h, it'll shutdown not hibernate. When I type only shutdown, it'll shutdown not a list of options of shutdown command. When I type shutdown asdasd, it'll return shutdown: bad date conversion: asdasd When I type shutdown -asdasd, it'll return shutdown: unknown option -a; Usage: shutdown [-S server] [-q] [-r|-h] [time[message]] shutdown -c [-S server]

What happen to my computer?

Recently I've install IS_V11.7_WINDOWS_CLIENT_MULTILI (IBM Datastage) and because of a requirement installation, I've change this registry NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation (default value : 2) become 0

How I can solve this problem?

[Shutdown cmd that I hope appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BriSk.jpg)

Comment: you are not using the shutdown command properly. What do you want the shutdown command to do for you?

Comment: I want the shutdown command runs properly again not shutdown automatically

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation that occurred on my Windows 2019 server running IBM Datastage which I finally figured out! I was getting this error when running shutdown.exe (usually trying to schedule a shutdown). None of the advanced parameters worked and even simply trying to display the parameters with /? resulted in:

> shutdown: bad date conversion /?

The problem was something was interfering with shutdown.exe in the path. Not sure what exactly, but it was throwing shutdown.exe off, producing this error. If you check your path and and notice that `C:\windows\system32` isn't first in the list, you will want to move that to the very top or beginning of your path and then relaunch you your shell. You'll notice performing a simple `shutdown /?` works again and shows all the parameters!

If you don't know how to find your path to check and see if the system32 folder is first, you can do it a few ways. From a DOS prompt simply type `PATH` or from a PS shell, type `$env:Path`. If you notice there are other paths in front of c:\windows\system32, you should move system32 to the very beginning of the path variable string. The most common way to do that is through the GUI: `Start> Run> sysdm.cpl. Click the Advanced tab and then environment variables. Search for 'Path' in the System variables section and Edit it. Then find C:\windows\system32 in the list and move it up to the top of the list. Then relaunch your shell.` C:\windows\system32 should now be finding shutdown.exe properly and the command should work again. Test it by using the /? parameter.

Hope this helps the community. This one was driving me nuts. :)